# Use Higher Order Component in React to format child components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am building a wrapper component that renders children components in a grid, either vertically or horizontally by taking the layout config as a prop:

```
class App extends React {
  render() {
    return (
      <WrapperComponent layout="horizontal">
        <ChildComponent1>
        <ChildComponent2/>
        <ChildComponent3/>
      </WrapperComponent/>
  }
}
```

I want to create a HOC that returns either a `<VerticalLayout/>` or a `<HorizontalLayout/>` component depending on the configuration passed to `<WrapperComponent/>`.

So the code pattern should be:
`const LayoutComponent = HOC(InputComponent)`.

I cannot pass `<WrapperComponent/>` as an input to `HOC`, as it needs to wrap the `<ChildComponents/>`, and it is the entry point for this layout:

How can I achieve the desired result with HOC implementation? I know that this can be achieved without HOC, but I specifically want to write this program by implementing HOC, as some of the tasks/code of `<VerticalLayout/>` and `<HorizontalLayout/>` will be the same and also because I want to practice writing HOCs.

Comment: `HOC(<InputComponent/>)` is not correct. HOC takes `component` as an argument, not `element`. Also, I don't think HOC really make sense here. Just a simple `if/else` condition in `render` method of `WrapperComponent` will do the job if I understood you correctly.

Comment: @PrakashSharma : Yeah my bad, it should have been HOC(InputConpoment). I know that for just two layouts, HOC doesn't make a lot of sense, but let's say that tomorrow I need to have a lot more layouts, then in that case, writing if else a lot of times will not be very elegant.

Comment: Where were you expecting to use `const LayoutComponent = HOC(<InputComponent/>)`? What's in `WrapperComponent`? Seems like in there is where you should have a `LayoutComponent` that is wrapped in your HOC?

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda: The idea is, that following the HOC code pattern, I pass a component to the HOC, which returns a component that renders the child components in the desired way as per the configuration (prop) passed to the `<WrapperComponent`>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel! it's already there and ready to be used, have a look at : https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/docs/API.md#branch

Basically you pass your configuration as a condition, something around these lines should do the trick:

```
branch(
  test: ( { config } => (config.isVertical),
  left: <VerticalLayout/>,
  right: <HorizontalLayout/>
)
```

Comment: Could you show the code for above implementation in the context of my question?

Comment: `branch` will return the HOC that will returns a `<VerticalLayout/>` or a `<HorizontalLayout/>` component depending on the passed configuration, ` { config }` is a simple props destruction assuming that there is a prop named config that will be used in the test condition.

Comment: So this is how I use this? `const HOC = branch(...);  class App extends React.Component { render() { return <HOC/>} }`

Comment: Yes I am looking for a similar pattern, but I can't use any third party libraries like Recompose.

Comment: Recompose is just a collection of useful HOCs, fancy name but the code is really simple to follow you can have your own `branch` like HOC if you want to, have a look at the source code  ;) https://github.com/acdlite/recompose/blob/master/src/packages/recompose/branch.js